# Is it possible to run the UK Direct Debit/GoCardless payment processor alongside Paypal Website Payments Standard?

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor, paypal, billingblock, paylater

Using Civi 4.6.18 with Wordpress, we have event registrations working smoothly using the Paypal Website Payments Standard payment processor. The next stage is to get memberships up and running and we want to use Veda's UK Direct Debit/GoCardless payment processor to facilitate recurring membership payments.

However, as soon as I enable the Direct Debit extension (I've not configured it yet and it's not been enabled on any contribution pages), my event contribution pages, which are set up to use Paypal, stop working correctly because the billing block is no longer being displayed as it should be when the user chooses the 'pay later' option. As a result the user is faced with validation errors that they can't fix.

If I disable the direct Debit extension, my Paypal event registration form works as it should.

Comment: For information I've also posted this as an issue on the extension's GitHub page: https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.payment.ukdirectdebit/issues/50

Comment: You mention version 4.6.x - but which one?  There have been many changes to billing block logic in the 4.6.x series.  Do you have the same problem with the latest version of 4.6?

Comment: I should have been more precise. We are running 4.6.18, and seeing the issue as described. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Graham - just for completeness - which version of gocardless? also i think there are some patches on their way for improving it with memberships. You may want to raise an issue on their github?

Comment: Hi Pete: I didn't even get to the point where the GoCardless extension was installed. All I did was install and enable the base Direct Debit extension, so I logged the issue there.